# How to continue with next set of tasks in Airflow after failure of one task?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

We are using Airflow to process the data of different applications. The data is processed using DBT. Our system have multiple application and each application has a unique id. We call 3 different DBT jobs via Airflow for each application. So per application, we need to run 3 airflow tasks to process data completely. If one of the task fails, we need to continue with first task of another application.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from utils.base_util import (default_args)
from utils.token_util import (fetch_token)
from utils.backend_util import get_applications

dag_id = 'winback'

START_DATE = Variable.get("AIRFLOW_START_DATE")
BO_URL = Variable.get("URL")
USER_NAME = Variable.get("AIRFLOW_USER_ID", default_var=os.environ.get("AIRFLOW_USER_ID"))
PASSWORD = Variable.get("AIRFLOW_USER_PASSWORD", default_var=os.environ.get("AIRFLOW_USER_PASSWORD"))
ENV = os.environ.get("ENVIRONMENT")
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
TAG_DBT_REVERSE_EL = Variable.get("TAG_DBT_REVERSE_EL")
TENANT = Variable.get("TENANT", default_var='SAAS')
ORG = os.environ.get("ORGANIZATION_NAME")
token = fetch_token(BO_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD)
application_list = get_applications(BO_URL, token)

if TENANT == 'SAAS':

    dag = DAG(
        dag_id, default_args=default_args, is_paused_upon_creation=False,
        schedule_interval=None, catchup=False, tags=["SEGMENTS", "DBT"])

    chain_tasks = []

    for application in application_list:
        application_id = str(application['application_id'])
        if str(application['is_seg_enabled']) == '1' and str(application['is_act_enabled']) == '1':
            suffix = application_id[application_id.find("-") + 1:]
            env_var = {
                'S3_STAGING_DIR': f"s3://{os.environ.get('QUERY_LOGS_BUCKET')}/dbt/",
                'REGION_NAME': os.environ.get("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"),
                'ENV': ENV,
                'ORG': ORG,
                'TENANT': TENANT,
                'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION': AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
                'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID': AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY': AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION': AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
                'APPLICATION_ID': application_id,
                .... 
             few more environment variables
            }

            winback = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='etl',
                                            image=f'blotout/db-ana:{TAG_DBT_ANALYTICS}',
                                            cmds=["/usr/local/bin/dbt"],
                                            arguments=['run', '--models', 'winback'],
                                            env_vars=env_var,
                                            name="winback",
                                            configmaps=['awskey'],
                                            task_id="winback_{}".format(suffix),
                                            get_logs=True,
                                            dag=dag,
                                            is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                                            )


            winback_activation_stats = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='etl',
                                                                 image=f'blotout/db-ana:{TAG_DBT_ANALYTICS}',
                                                                 cmds=["/usr/local/bin/dbt"],
                                                                 arguments=['run', '--models', 'winback_activation_stats'],
                                                                 env_vars=env_var,
                                                                 name="winback_activation_stats",
                                                                 configmaps=['awskey'],
                                                                 task_id="winback_activation_stats_{}".format(suffix),
                                                                 get_logs=True,
                                                                 dag=dag,
                                                                 is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                                                                 )


            winback_segments_sync = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='etl',
                                                        image=f'blotout/rev-el:{TAG_DBT_REVERSE_EL}',
                                                        cmds=["python3"],
                                                        arguments=['providers/activation/segments_init.py', 'winback', application_id],
                                                        env_vars=env_var,
                                                        name="winback_segments_sync",
                                                        configmaps=['awskey'],
                                                        task_id="winback_segments_sync_{}".format(suffix),
                                                        get_logs=True,
                                                        dag=dag,
                                                        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                                                        )


            chain_tasks.append(winback)
            chain_tasks.append(winback_activation_stats)
            chain_tasks.append(winback_segments_sync)


for i,val in enumerate(chain_tasks[:-1]):
    val.set_downstream(chain_tasks[i+1])

globals()[dag_id] = dag
```

Currently if one of the task fails, all the other subsequent tasks are marked as skipped. We do not want them to be skipped, but the tasks for another application should start execution.

Comment: try to check trigger rule https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules

Comment: Hi @PankajSingh, I saw the link mentioned above but that has only 2 branches. The number of branches in my case will be decided at runtime based on number of apps. Is it possible for you to suggest the code changes in the above snippet so that I could implement and test it?

Comment: @azaveri7: in general there is a reader expectation here that if you are pointed in the right direction (e.g. with a code snippet) you can modify it for your own needs. Give it a try - you may find your IDE will prompt you with object methods or parameter names anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As Pankaj mentioned in his comment, you can leverage [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules) to run downstream tasks when a given task fails.

With that said, if a given task doesn't depend on an upstream task succeeding and the task doesn't need to wait for the other task to complete, it might make sense to not use `set_downstream` on that task. For example, if both `winback_activation_stats` and `winback_segments_sync` depend on `winback`, but have no relationship between each other, you could instead do...

```py
winback >> [winback_activation_stats, winback_segments_sync]
```

This will result in `winback_activation_stats` and `winback_segments_sync` waiting for the `winback` task, but `winback_activation_stats` will run whether `winback_segments_sync` succeeds or not and vice versa.

Comment: Hi @RNHTTR, lets say we have 3 apps, appid -> 0001, 0002, 0003. So we need to run the above tasks in the same order thrice, one for each app. If any one task fails for an app, all the subsequent tasks are skipped. Can you suggest changes in the above code snippet ?